Marking a Cookie as Partitioned in Django
This is my view:
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@require_http_methods(['GET'])
def set_csrf_token(request):
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Set CSRF cookie'})

I set this cookie in a Cross-Origin context so I also have to enable in my settings.py:
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

However, my browser (FireFox and Chrome) both require the use of Partitioned cookies since I'm sending this cookie with "None; Secure" which the browser interprets as a 3rd-party server or Cross-Origin
Yet, Django appears to lack a setting like CSRF_COOKIE_PARTITIONED which would allow me to mark my cookie as Partitioned
So I ask what would be an elegant solution to setting my cookie as Partitioned?
Edit: the Partitioned attribute is not actually required but more so recommended. It sounds like both browsers are moving towards this attribute being required though

There are no elegant solutions yet.
The work to get support for Partitioned into Python stblib is complete, but they missed the 3.13 release window - so as of yet, they are waiting for a new window to merge upstream.
Django maintainers seemingly don't want to do too much work for this until upstream support in stblib is confirmed, either. However - this thread (specifically the comment this URL leads to) contains an alleged workaround for the CSRF token, using a custom Django middleware:
# Author: Terence Honles
...
from http import cookies

...
cookies.Morsel._flags.add("partitioned")
cookies.Morsel._reserved.setdefault("partitioned", "Partitioned")

class CookiePartitioningMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(
        self, request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponseBase
    ) -> HttpResponseBase:
        for name in (
            getattr(settings, f"{prefix}_COOKIE_NAME")
            for prefix in ("CSRF", "SESSION", "LANGUAGE")
            if getattr(settings, f"{prefix}_COOKIE_SECURE")
        ):
            if cookie := response.cookies.get(name):
                cookie["Partitioned"] = True

        return response

If this type of approach doesn't work, you can try patching http.cookies yourself using the PR. Comments in the pull request also include a rough implementation draft.
